# I can not install tensorflow and keras with anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

I just installed individual edition of anaconda. After that I immediately went into the base(root) environment to install tensorflow and keras because I need them for a project and sadly I cannot install them.

By manually trying to install tensorflow via the anaconda navigator application I get the following error

> ```
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
> to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
>
> Specifications:
>
>   - tensorflow -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*|3.7.*']
>
> Your python: python=3.8
>
> If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
> When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
> not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
> change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
> that.
>
> The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:
>
>   - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
>   - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
>
> Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0
> ```

I get a similar error when I am trying to install keras. From the explanation I understand that python 3.8 does not support these packages? In this case, what can I do? I need to be able to use these libraries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any package you need that only works on python 3.8? If not, perhaps consider downgrading your python to 3.7

Comment: I wouldnt mind doing that. I just installed anaconda and it comes automatically with python 3.8. Any idea if I can downgrade the python that the base environment is using?

Comment: Downgrade.  The whole purpose of conda and venv is to create virtual environments.

Comment: Should I downgrade or create a new environment with 3.7 python?

Comment: run ```conda install python=3.7``` in your current environment, or just start a new environment.

Comment: I just made a new environment with 3.7 to use for my projects that require keras and tensorflow. I figured it was wiser than messing with the default python of root environment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Had to go back to python 3.7. Also the message

```
Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0
```

I believe is not referencing your CUDA version but the driver for your GPU card. Look at the installed modules and makes sure you are using CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN 7.6.5. Documentation is here. As for the GPU driver I had to go to the Nvidia website and find a older driver that was compatible with CUDA 10.1. You would think by now the Tensorflow folks would provide this advise.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer and for the information! I finally decided to create a new environment in which I installed 3.7.7 python. After this, I downloaded tensorflow and keras in this environment and it seems to work perfectly. The only thing that changed is that when I open the navigator, I choose the "applications on <newenv_name> and I run jupyter from there. One thing that surprised me is that I had to install jupyter again in this new environment. Is this normal or did I make a mistake somewhere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is normal. Each time you create a new environment you have to install the applications like jupyter or spyder.

Comment: Ok, thanks a ton for the information. I appreciate it, have a good day.